# How can I remove the dots in my chart?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I'm using the Silverlight Toolkit's chart, and how can I remove the LineSeries dots? I want only the lines, no dots. I've tried collapsing it, but then they became yellow, the lines too:

```
                         <toolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="Control">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </Style>
                        </toolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the effect you want can be achieved by setting the MarkerHeight and MarkerWidth of the LineSeries object to 0.